# DNS server and fallback outside home

Tags: dns

I have my own DNS server at home to access local names, and that is working fine.

Then I have my laptop, now obviously my laptop leaves the home now and then, therefore it accesses different nets outside my home, and my DNS server is not accessible there... So I figured that I would just add Google as secondary DNS...

But actually, when I do that, then suddenly I can't access my local stuff, the page won't resolve (at home that is, obviously), like my laptop is getting a quicker response from Google's DNS or something, because it can't find anything on the addresses I use locally.

If I then remove the secondary DNS, and keeps my own, then it works fine again...

So do I somehow need to seperate what DNS's to use on what nets? I already use sepperate DNS settings when I connect using my 3G modem, but when I use hotspots it seems to use the same settings regardless (at least in the train), also can it differ wired connections?...
Is there another solution?

OS: Windows 7 Ultimate, x64

**EDIT:** Currently trying this "hack/fix" out for the time being:
http://blog.johnruiz.com/2011/12/windows-does-not-always-honor-dns-order.html

Comment: What *precisely* is the problem you experience from home? What does "it can't find anything on the address I use locally" mean?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's your OS but check what's the priority of Google DNS over your local home ones, this could solve this.

Moreover, if you suffer of this problem when 'coming back' home (after using OpenDNS or Google's DNS at work for example), this could also be some dns caching issue.

Check the priority of your DNS + check how to clear DNS cache on your OS. :)

Comment: Gave a hint to do different searches, thanks... According to a blog post, windows apparently doesn't always honor the order the DNS's are listed in, although it clearly states "DNS server addresses, in order of use:"... *sigh*...